# Adding font awsome to dropdown bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this kind of dropdown in boostrap 3

```
 <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> Dashboard</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

The problem is here that txt gone right to the icon, i want to text stay under the icon in the middle, and icon also in the middle at top of the text, when i add long text under the icon thta all stay in the middle

Here is working bootply
http://www.bootply.com/ZhwSteTLgw

What i need is this

[image]

But whne i add long txt all to stay in the middle?

**UPDATE
Solution**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i><span class="show">Dashboard</span></a>


ul > li > a
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/pNuWtf76H8)

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a style="width:auto" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle col-md-12 text-center" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x col-md-12 "></i> <p class="col-md-12 ">Dashboard</p></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="dropdown" style="display: table-caption;">
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="margin-left: 18PX;"> 
   <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> Dashboard</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

CHECK THIS